# Laravel determine which controller returned error , laravel breeze

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I'm using laravel breeze and I have two popups modals in the header, one for login and one for signup, when an authentication error occurs I want to: A) open the modal responsible and B) show the error in the correct modal, any ideas?

Comment: Use javascript for this. Instead of posting form direclty, send it through ajax() or fetch() and in response , determine the output and show the corresponding modal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `$request->validateWithBag` instead of `$request->validate` and checked for the "Bag" in script section with `$errors->nameOfBag->has('email')` and it worked as needed